# onedrive new api for upload conflict

Tags: onedrive

I am using the onedrive new api to do resumable upload by doc:
http://onedrive.github.io/items/upload_large_files.htm#create-an-upload-session

even I set the param name.conflictBehavior: replace
after the last fragment be uploaded, it still return the 409 conflict error

Even I change the behavior to rename, the same response got.

I wonder if I make fail parameters while create upload session:

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer <access_token>',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
params = {'@name.conflictBehavior': 'replace'}
try:
    res = request.post(url, headers=headers, data=params)
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

after doing that I could get the upload url with param behind the url.
but after the last fragment uploaded, the 409 error occurred.

Is this a bug or just the parameters I pass are wrong, I have no idea.

Comment: yes, if there is no file with the same name existed in the onedrive storage, the error will not happened. In addition, I tried the error handle listed in the api doc with uploading the file with new metadata by http://onedrive.github.io/items/upload_large_files.htm#handle-commit-errors . the error return with 400 invalid argument. I wonder if this is the error I made or the bug this api is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we have a bug here where we don't honor the @name.conflictBehavior annotation in that scenario. We're working on a fix.

Comment: I have report this bug in support site and found out someone reported this bug, too. 
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/7